# Calculating age in a T-SQL query

Tags: sql-server, database, t-sql

I know this has been asked but I found the following code that appears to be working correctly and just wanted to have all the pros here take a quick look at it.

I work in banking and need it to work 100% of the time and I've noticed that a lot of the queries can sometimes be incorrect. Also `N.NameBirthdate` is the column I am pulling from my database.

Thank you in advance.

```
SELECT 
   CASE 
      WHEN (MONTH(GETDATE()) * 100) + DAY(GETDATE()) >= (MONTH(N.NameBirthdate) * 100) +  DAY(N.NameBirthdate) 
      THEN DATEDIFF(Year, N.NameBirthdate, GETDATE()) 
      ELSE DATEDIFF(Year, N.NameBirthdate, GETDATE())-1 
   END AS 'Age',
```

Comment: Instead of asking if the code works as you want, why not set up some unit tests to prove that it does? In other words define a data set of birth date, current date and age, and test your code against it. Your test data should include 'odd' cases like leap years, birthday on Feb 29th etc. If your code passes the tests then by definition it is correct for your purposes.

Answer (score 2):

Well, I'm not sure exactly if that will work 100% but are you open to other query ideas? I always use this:

```
SELECT FLOOR(DATEDIFF(d, N.NameBirthDate, GETDATE()) / 365.25) AS Age
```

if I need to calculate an age. The 365.25 is to allow for leap years.

But you may encounter slight inaccuracies if the person has not experienced a leap year and depending on the time of day the query is run. See [this](http://www.wiseowl.co.uk/blog/s216/calculating_age_in_sql_server.htm) for more info

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(yy, BirthDate, GETDATE()) - CASE
    WHEN MONTH(BirthDate) > MONTH(GETDATE())
          OR (MONTH(BirthDate) = MONTH(GETDATE())
             AND DAY(BirthDate) > DAY(GETDATE()))
    THEN 1
    ELSE 0
END AS Age;
```

Answer (score 0):

What you have should work. I might use a variation though just because I find it a bit more readable / obvious:

```
SELECT DATEDIFF(Year, N.NameBirthdate,getdate()) - 
    (case when month(N.NameBirthdate) > month(getdate()) or (month(N.NameBirthdate) = month(getdate()) and day(N.NameBirthdate) > day(getdate()) ) then 1 else 0 end)
```

To me, this makes sense because that's how you (or I do), determine someone's age. OK: what year were you born and what year is it now? What month are we in now? Is it your birth month? What day is it?

I personally don't like the leap year approach. First of all, it's not 365.25, but .24. To be precise it's 365.24219647. If you use .25 you will be wrong. Example: http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/d41d8/8267

Answer (score 0):

I know that this is old but I was looking around for a quick way to properly calculate someone's age and I couldn't find anything. These answers work fine but I did not want any case statement and I wanted it to be completely accurate so I developed this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()-COALESCE(DOB,GETDATE()))-DATEPART(YY,0)
```

Ex.

```
DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()-COALESCE(DOB,GETDATE()))
```

DATEPART(YY,'07-30-2014' - '10-03-2000') = 1913...

1913 - DATEPART(YY,0)...

1913 - 1900 = 13

I like this method better because if the DOB is null then you will get 0 and no matter what the date system is, subtracting `DATEPART(YY,0)` will account for it. So instead of 1913 you would have 1917 - 1904 = 13 if somehow the date system was 1904(I know excel has this, does DBs??? IDK; IDC) Also, it's only 61 characters. If you DB allows for empty sets then you can use `NULLIF` like so:

```
SELECT DATEPART(YY,GETDATE()-COALESCE(NULLIF(DOB,''),GETDATE()))-DATEPART(YY,0)
```